# Implicit conversion while comparing numeric values in Python

Tags: python

While working on an issue, I stumbled at something I cannot really undestand on my own.

I have a variable:
`a = pow(2, 1024)`

Its type is long int. If I try casting it explicitly to float, like `float(a)`, I receive `OverflowError`. The number is too big to fit in 64bit float, so it's understandable.

Then I try implicit cast, through mutliplying it by a float number:

`b = a * 11.0`

Once again, the `OverflowError` occurs, which is fine, because according to [python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#arithmetic-conversions), implicit conversion from long int to float happens. So the result is like before.

Finally, I try comparison:

`a > 11.0`
returns `True`. The `OverflowError` doesn't occur. And that confuses me a lot. How does the Python comparison mechanism work, if it doesn't require numerics to be in the same format? Accordind to [this](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#numeric-types-int-float-long-complex),

> Python fully supports mixed arithmetic: when a binary arithmetic operator has operands of different numeric types, the operand with the “narrower” type is widened to that of the other, where plain integer is narrower than **long integer is narrower than floating point** is narrower than complex. **Comparisons between numbers of mixed type use the same rule.** The constructors int(), long(), float(), and complex() can be used to produce numbers of a specific type.

My question is, why `a` is not being cast to float in forementioned comparison?

The version of Python I'm using is 2.7.15. Thanks in an advance

Comment: related: [Ляп в Питоне: x + 1.0 < x](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/748183/23044) (see links there)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the [source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Objects/floatobject.c#L400):

```
/* Comparison is pretty much a nightmare.  When comparing float to float,
 * we do it as straightforwardly (and long-windedly) as conceivable, so
 * that, e.g., Python x == y delivers the same result as the platform
 * C x == y when x and/or y is a NaN.
 * When mixing float with an integer type, there's no good *uniform* approach.
 * Converting the double to an integer obviously doesn't work, since we
 * may lose info from fractional bits.  Converting the integer to a double
 * also has two failure modes:  (1) a long int may trigger overflow (too
 * large to fit in the dynamic range of a C double); (2) even a C long may have
 * more bits than fit in a C double (e.g., on a 64-bit box long may have
 * 63 bits of precision, but a C double probably has only 53), and then
 * we can falsely claim equality when low-order integer bits are lost by
 * coercion to double.  So this part is painful too.
 */
```

As such, the potential pitfalls of conversion are taken into account.

Comment: but this does not say how it is actually done.. Only that it is painful..

Comment: How it *is* done is in the source code just below that comment. Particularly around [line 484](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Objects/floatobject.c#L484).

Comment: Uh, that really is painful. Would the case be the same for PyPy as well?

Comment: Probably, but is it actually an issue? None of these edge cases break the intuitive comparison operators. If you need to check that it fits a float, then do a `float(a)` and catch the exception.

Comment: I needed my code to be as little exception-driven as possible. Anyway, I've changed the way it works so now I don't happen to have a long int that exceeds float. I will mark your post as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

The exact error is `OverflowError: int too large to convert to float`

Which also means that any `int` that generates that error is by definition **bigger** then any possible float. So just checking if it's bigger should return `True`.

I'm not entirely sure, but I wouldn't be surprised if the implementation is just catching this error in the background (when trying to cast to `float`) and returning `True` in that case.

That is always true with the exception of `float('inf')` which is a special case that should return `False` (and does)

Comment: this is just a guess

Comment: @Chris_Rands I'm not sure if that's the exact implementation but that's the logic of it, because the fact is - it works (as OP mentioned)

Comment: `float(-a)` also triggers `OverflowError`. 
`-a > 11.0` return `false`. I think that's not the case

Comment: But in that case one is clearly positive and one is negative, there's no reason to check anything else besides that (with comparing to `0` of both elements).

Comment: Again, i'm sure by description isn't accurate but it's a logical step to understanding what is actually going on